# Does rails ActiveJob retry_on work with delayed_job gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Rails ActiveJob has a [retry_on](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on) hook that allows you to customize retry behavior. For example:

```rb
  retry_on AnotherCustomAppException, wait: ->(executions) { executions * 2 }
```

Rails also passes the current retry number as `executions` with the `job_data` and there's a `retry_job` method for further customization.

However, if you use the [delayed_job_active_record](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) gem as your backend, it looks like there's a separate config called [max_attempts](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs) that controls the retry behavior.

My question is, if you use the delayed_job_active_record backend, can you still use `retry_on` without issues?

If you can't use `retry_on`, then what would be an appropriate strategy for imitating that customization of rescues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `delayed_job` as a backend to `ActiveJob`, you end up with two retry mechanisms: first from `ActiveJob`, configurable using the `retry_on` method, and second from `delayed_job`, which is controlled by the `max_attempts` variable.

You can turn off the retry behaviour from delayed_job with the following:

```
# in config/initializers/delayed_job.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
```

Now your retries are controlled entirely by the ActiveJob `retry_on` call, which should result in predictable behaviour.